# Best way to display plus/minus or pros/cons short sentences

Tags: website-design, gui-design, icons, lists

I have information in short sentences (bullet list) and each bullet could be pros/cons or plus/minus toward a product. What is the best way to display it nicely?

For example:

```
+ Price is cheap

+ Many people bought this and found out that it is very easy to use

- It's somewhat ugly in design

- They don't have many retail locations yet
```

I tended to put `+` and `-` as the bullet image for each line but then it seems to look ugly. Is there any other way or examples of how people do this in web design?

**UPDATE 1:**
I had some ideas but could not find good example. How about:

- Sub-header saying Pros/Cons and just any bullet image
- Text color: red vs green?
- Background color: light red vs. light green?

etc...

More examples from Stackoverflow (using -1 as a mark of negative). Or Quora/Digg also using points. Dunno...

**UPDATE 2:**

*Added one important piece of information*: the pluses/pros always go together. The minuses/cons are the same - All grouped together.

Attempt to do the arrow based on vision below

[image]

**UPDATE 3:**

Potential grouping of positives vs. negatives.

[image]

**UPDATE 4:**

Use red and green left border to market Pros/Cons section. Then have thin separator for each line:

[image]

**UPDATE 5:**

Use two indicators of Pros/Cons: green/red thumbs and the words Good/Bad. Also light color bullet points to market each line:

[image]

**UPDATE 6:**

Use two indicators of Pros/Cons: Good/Bad words and the underline color:

[image]

**UPDATE 7:**

Use two indicators of Pros/Cons: Good/Bad words and the color of each bullet point:

[image]

**UPDATE 8:**

Use simple smiley icons with red/green and vertical align with the bullet also in red/green:

[image]

Comment: Any other context you can provide about how you're using these pros/cons? You ask about the "best" way to display them "nicely", but there's no answer to that question. Instead, think in terms of a concrete, measurable goal. The right choice will depend a lot on your application and your users. Determining which implementation is "best" will require some testing and validation. For example: I would not expect the styled border option in update #4 to be among the best solutions, but it's always hypothetically possible that it could be an ideal fit for your particular application.

Comment: I didn't pay attention much to wording here. Pros/Cons could be used to. Actually it's more for services review, not exactly product review. But concept is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One suggestion if you will, try placing the negatives and positives **side by side**. It can help make the users see a clear cut distinction right off the bat when you have a red and a green list laid next to each other rather than one following the other. So, you have a list of "The good stuff" and "The not so good stuff" there for **direct comparison**. It also helps to show if there are more good points than bad (since it's more difficult to make that comparison when the lists are stacked).
Apart from that, I think you've figured out most of the different ways in which to highlight the content.

A word of caution: Depending on your audience, you might want to rethink the coloring. Different colors have different interpretations across cultures.

Comment: What do you think on my Update 8?

Comment: Something along those lines. Now if you compare reading your update 7 vs update 8, in 7 you read all the good stuff and then all the bad stuff. You keep moving up and down to weigh the options. In 8, you read 1 good point, 1 bad point, it facilitates a conversation in your own mind. Like hearing 2 people debate rather than listening to 2 monologues.

Answer (score 2):

The bullet style in Update 2 is too representative of a trend. You see this type of indicator in stocks or other performance monitoring to represent a positive of negative trend since the last measurement. See a snap from New Relic below:

[image]

Update 3 & 5 look to me like I might get to vote or weigh-in with my opinion in some way.

I didn't expect it, but I really think **Update 8** provides the reader with a quick way to judge the balance of good to bad, something less obvious in the other styles. I can easily determine which list is longer and make a judgement based on that. With the other treatments, it's not as obvious whether the 'good' outweighs the 'bad'.

Answer (score 1):

I have found ✓ is the best bullet for such list which intends to build credibility  or value of a product/service. ✓ symbol is provided by Unicode and can be used as Text

BUT

If you were looking to use it as bullet list, you might have to use image icons. http://www.iconfinder.com/search/?q=tick

Go for green tick-marks, as green adds another positive layer of impression.

Comment: I try to think out of the box about just picking bullet point image. Having check mark everywhere seems redundant. Plus what about the negative one? It has to have both.

Comment: @HP You could use a check mark for pros and an X or a dash for cons. Green and red, respectively, to further differentiate as Salman pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use UP arrow and DOWN arrow for positive and negative points respectively.

**Arrows should be those filled up triangles just like the ones shown in Stock market ratings**.

Also, you can fill them *green* for positive and *red* for negative display.

Refer this image.Bullets can be in this manner.

[image]

Comment: Would it clutter the line with bunch of arrows? Since I plan to have a group of, let say, 5 pluses on top, and 5 minuses on bottom.

Comment: Let the arrows be small colored triangles. It will not look clustered; it will give a vertical stack look and will make the positive and negative points very clear.

Comment: Answer edited and image added for your reference.

Comment: you can adjust size of triangles according to your convenience.

Comment: I modified the answer with my example using your idea. It still looks clutter. The first 3 bullets are all green/positive/plus. I am thinking of a way to have a single "indicator" of "plus" for the group.

Comment: Then, you can single top-facing arrow at the beginning of the positive points and similarly one single bottom-facing arrow for the negative points.Then, it wont look clustered.But frankly speaking, what you have implemented in the updated question, is looking fair enough.

Comment: So I just posted UPDATE 3 with what I was thinking. Still not 100% happy although I like it better. The reason I am not happy is because the bullets now seem somewhat "losely" where they are placing relatively to each other. I'm wondering if it's just spacing or should I have bullet dot in front of them...

Comment: Yes.They are looking a bit lousy.Why dont you just remove the whole container and keep only the thumbs-up and thumbs-down with green and red filled up,if you can try?

Comment: Would want to make sure the shades of red/green are chosen to be likely to appear different for a red-green colourblind user. Obviously hard to get away from red=bad, green=good, but a dark green / bright red might still allow a colourblind user to easily differentiate.

Comment: I just modified with a bunch of options. What do you think? I seem to like UPDATE 5 or UPDATE 7.

Comment: If its compulsory to write "Good" and "Bad", then I would go for Update 7.Its really looking neat.
Even Update 4 seems nice.

Comment: I can change the wording. But I think I'm pretty much happy with UPDATE 8 (thinner font with typography style). Also follow @rk advise on placing them side-by-side. What do you think?

Comment: I don't think that this is a good option. I think that in the mental modal of a user, up and down icons in a list suggest that he can change te order. For instance, here on StackExchange we use them to rate the answer (and thus: try to change the order)

Comment: These types of arrows typically represent a change in value since a previous period, ie, a trend and I don't think they are valid here.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to make a general statement. But I would group the pros and cons as in your example "update 3". Some users want to catch the cons or pros quickly. The example "update 2" has too many redundancies and is (IMO) too cluttered.